# Choose X s.t. $\Pr[X \geq k] = 1/k$

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, approximation

I am trying to implement an algorithm to approximate the weight of a Minimum Spanning Tree, as described [here](http://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/~oded/PTW/sublin.pdf) (p. 8-10). In the pseudo-code *ApproxConnectedComps(G, s)*, p. 9, there is a passage where they choose a random maximum number of iterations, $X$, such that $\Pr[X \geq k] = 1/k$.

With my rather limited skills in probability, I was trying to work this out, but found myself stumped. The only way I found to solve it was to estimate the number of vertices $k$, and then choose $X$ uniformly random in the range $[1,k]$, which gives $\Pr[X = k] = 1/k$. If I'm not entirely mistaken, this should satisfy the condition stated in the pseudo-code, but it feels.. a bit off. Am I on the right track, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, $$\Pr[X \ge k] \ne \Pr[X = k],$$ unless $\Pr[X > k] = 0$.  So your use of a uniform distribution does not satisfy the stated criterion.

Let's consider what the condition $$\Pr[X \ge k] = 1/k$$ would imply about an integer-valued random variable $X$.  Clearly, $X \ge 1$, so $X$ is a positive integer.  Then $$\Pr[X = k] = \Pr[X \ge k] - \Pr[X \ge k+1] = \frac{1}{k} - \frac{1}{k+1} = \frac{1}{k(k+1)},$$ and we specifically have $$\begin{align*}
\Pr[X = 1] &= \frac{1}{2}, \\ \Pr[X = 2] &= \frac{1}{6}, \\ \Pr[X = 3] &= \frac{1}{12}, \\ \Pr[X = 4] &= \frac{1}{20}, \end{align*}$$  and so forth.

If the goal is to simulate this random variable--that is to say, create an algorithm that will produce realizations of $X$ that follow this distribution--then one simple method is to generate a continuous uniform random variable $U$ between $0$ and $1$ (e.g., some function like `rand()`).  Then take the reciprocal of this number to get $1/U$, and round *downward* to the nearest integer.  So for example, `floor(1/rand())` is what you might use on a computer.  This will give you the desired realization of $X$.  I leave it to you as an exercise to show that this actually works.

Comment: I feel like I'm very close to understanding, but I'm not quite following the example $\Pr[X = k] = \Pr[X \geq k] - \Pr[X \geq k + 1]$. Why do we want to look at the event $X = k$ and why can you subtract $\Pr[X \geq k + 1]$? I'm not quite sure how this step leads to the conclusion that I could use the reciprocal of a uniform distribution between $[0, 1]$.

Comment: We are interested in $\Pr[X = k]$ because this tells us the probability that $X$ equals a given number and characterizes the probability distribution.  If $X$ is a positive integer, the probability that $X$ equals $k$ is equal to the probability that $X$ is at least $k$, minus the probability that $X$ is at least $k+1$.

Comment: In so far as the simulation part, this is something that is not directly related to the earlier computation.  You can, in fact, arrive at it by considering only $\Pr[X \ge k] = 1/k$, by observing that for a continuous uniform distribution on $(0,1)$, $\Pr[U \le u] = u$ for any $0 \le u \le 1$; hence $\Pr[U \le 1/k] = 1/k$ for any integer $k \ge 1$; consequently $$\Pr[1/U \ge k] = 1/k$$ for any integer $k \ge 1$, which suggests that $X = \lfloor 1/U \rfloor$ will satisfy the condition $\Pr[X \ge k] = 1/k$.

Comment: This was very helpful. Thank you for the insight.